# How to get error logs via email?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter i want to receive error logs via email. For example, if any error message occurs on my website , i want to get an email about it.

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom Error Handler: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

This way you can do whatever you want with errors ...  email, write to a log etc...